# Why does uniq -z returns duplicates?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, cygwin, uniq

I have the file `sorted.txt`:

```
$cat sorted.txt  
bash  
fosh  
hack  
hack
```

If I do `uniq`:

```
$uniq sorted.txt  
bash  
fosh  
hack
```

If I do `uniq -z` I get:

```
$uniq -z sorted.txt  
bash  
fosh  
hack  
hack
```

I.e. in `uniq -z` I get duplicates! I was expecting that the only difference in the output of `uniq sorted.txt` and `uniq -z sorted.txt` is the separating character.
Why am I getting duplicates in `uniq -z`?

Answer (score 5):

The `-z` option tells `uniq` to use a 0 byte instead of newline as the separator between records. Since your file doesn't have any 0 bytes, it's treated as one record.

Comment: So it first converts the `\n` to a `\0` which effectively makes a single record and then tries to remove duplicates but since it is a single record it does not find duplicates?But then why does it print this single record in multiple lines if `\n` has already been removed?

Comment: It doesn't convert anything. It's looking for `\0` in the input as the record separator. It treats `\n` as an ordinary character within the records.

Comment: iow, the output is exactly as the input, which is considered as one single long entry. If you use an unsorted file, the result will be more apparent. See [uniq(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uniq)